# Importing a DB is throwing 1064 an error in your SQL syntax and/or encoding errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sequelpro

I've been trying to export a DB from a hosted phpMyAdmin interface and import it locally either into phpMyAdmin or using SequelPro. This never used to be a problem. But recently when I import the DB in my local phpAdmin GUI I get an error of the sort:

```
[ERROR in query 36] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 22
```

What query should I run or how should I inspect `query 36` or `line 22`. I suspect that maybe an entry has corrupted, resulting in the error.

If, instead, I try to import the DB into SequelPro I get an error of this sort:

```
File read error

An error occurred when reading the file, as it could not be read in the encoding you selected (Autodetect - Unicode (UTF-8)).

Only 0 queries were executed.
```

Following up on this error, I've tried importing with Encoding set to `Western (Mac OS Roman)`. But I still get the same error.

The DB admittedly is mostly encoded in UTF-8. But there are a few tables that are encoded as cp1252 / latin1_swedish_ci. This was always so and never gave any export / import problems.

Moreover, another possible issue is the fact that most of the table Types are MyISAM. However a minority are InnoDB, for a reason. But then again this never gave us issue.

Any clues or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: any luck finding an answer? I have the same problem.

Comment: There are few ways to get round this. Both are tedious and annoying:
1. Export batches of tables and reimport them a batch at a time.
2. Export the DB with with no compression and import it in the same way. I had a couple of tables that contained too much data for the import function (on a crappy server + phpMyAdmin), so I excluded them from the export.